# Mongoid - get a field from document

Tags: ruby-on-rails, mongodb, mongoid

I have the following model

```
class MyModel
  field :title,           type: String
  field :url,             type: String
end
```

I would like to make a query that will return only the title field for each document.

How can I do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`only` or `without`](http://mongoid.org/en/origin/docs/options.html#standard):

> `Queryable#only`
>
> Limit the fields that are returned to the provided fields.
>
> `Queryable#without`
>
> Limit the fields that are returned everything except the provided fields.

So you'd say:

```
MyModel.query_method_calls.only(:title)
# or
MyModel.query_method_calls.without(:url)
```

Note that `only` will make a mess of things if you're using Mongoid3 with the Identity Map enabled, you'll get half-formed objects stuck in the identity map cache and end up wondering where all the strange `nil` attributes are coming from. If this applies to you then bypass Mongoid and use the [underlying Moped interface](http://mongoid.org/en/moped/docs/driver.html#behaviour):

> `Query#select`
>
> Select the fields you want returned.

This approach would look like:

```
MyModel.collection.find(...).select(:title => 1)
```

You'd be working with hashes instead of Mongoid objects in this case.